# Java listener on dialog close

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, windowlistener

I have a Java app that displays a list from a database. Inside the class is the following code to open a new dialog for data entry:

```
@Action
public void addNewEntry() {
    JFrame mainFrame = ADLog2App.getApplication().getMainFrame();
    addNewDialog = new AddNewView(mainFrame, true);
    addNewDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(mainFrame);
    addNewDialog.addContainerListener(null);
    ADLog2App.getApplication().show(addNewDialog);
}
```

How do you add a listener to the main class to detect when the addNewDialog window is closed, so that I can call a refresh method and refresh the list from the database.

Comment: What do you mean by the "main class"?  The class that defines `addNewEntry`?  The `JFrame`? What the heck is `AddNewView`?  What library is that from?

Comment: Have you looked into Windowlisteners? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html

Comment: Sorry, 'AddNewView' is the JDialog being opened.

Comment: Since Simiil's link from 2011 now points to the starting page of the JDK 20 documentation here is the same documentation (WindowListener), but from JDK 8. This link should hopefully hold until at least 2030: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html and in JDK 20:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If `AddNewView` is a [`Window`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) such as a [`Dialog`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html) or [`JDialog`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html), you could use the [Window.addWindowListener(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#addWindowListener%28java.awt.event.WindowListener%29). That is, in your main class, you do

```
addNewDialog.addWindowListener(someWindowListener);
```

where `someWindowListener` is some [`WindowListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) (for instance a [`WindowAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html)) which overrides / implemetnns [`windowClosed`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosed%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29).

A more complete example, using an anonymous class, could look like

```
addNewDialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        refreshMainView();
    }
});
```

---

**Relevant links:**

- [Official Tutorial: How to Write Window Listeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)

Comment: Great links.  In regard to the ones to the JavaDocs.  Until such times as [bug report 7090875](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875) (an RFE) is resolved, any chance of you throwing a '7' into any search for the doc for a class (or otherwise linking to the version 7 docs)?

Comment: Yeah. Perhaps it's time to start referring to v7... Hadn't struck my mind. I'll do it from now on. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks back.  The sooner that people start linking to the v. 7 docs, the sooner Google will return those links over the v. 6 links.  Of course, if the RFE is implemented, it will all become moot.

Comment: Just to add note that `windowClosed` is called when dispose() method are used, and `windowClosing` is called when user press 'X' button on top-right of the `JDialog`.

Answer (score 8):

you have to add [WindowListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) and override [windowClosing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) Event, if event occured then just returs some flag, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613577/java-how-do-i-prevent-windowclosing-from-actually-closing-the-window/7613768#7613768)