# Kill a Thread On Dialog Close

Tags: java

I have a thread that runs in a loop, and would like to kill a thread once a dialog that started the thread closes. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: What type of dialog? What context? Please do tell the details necessary for us to give an intelligent answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `interrupt()` for the thread. This won't stop the thread, however, unless you do something about it inside the thread loop.

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (shouldLoop() && !isInterrupted()) {
            . . .
        }
    }
}();

// somewhere else:
t.interrupt(); // will exit thread on next loop iteration
```

If you don't want to use `interrupt()` (say, you don't have a reference to the thread), you can set a flag somewhere that is accessible to the thread code. You still need to check it in the thread loop and exit the loop (and the `run()` method) to exit the thread.

Comment: @RyanNaddy - You have to write the loop in such a way that it frequently checks `isInterrupted()` (or whatever flag you use) and exits the loop when the flag becomes set.

Comment: I did it just like the example and it seems to exit the loop correctly. `while(true && !this.isInterrupted()){` is what I am using.

Answer (score 0):

You [could listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652821/java-listener-on-dialog-close) to the dialogs close event, and [interrupt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) the thread.