# How to detect the JFrame is closed?

Tags: java, swing, operating-system

I tried a `addWindowListener` and implement the `windowClosing`, it works, when I press the close button, but when I use `Cmd+Q` to close, the `windowClosing` is not being called, how can I solve it? Do I need to detect `Cmd+Q` on mac, `Alt + F4` on windows via key listener? Is that a general listener for closing window, whatever via the close button or keyboard, or event `Ctrl+Alt+Delete` or `Cmd+Option+Esc` to focus kill? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061194/swing-on-osx-how-to-trap-command-q

Comment: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/containers/10windows/12frameclose.html

Comment: @TedWong Did you find a solution to your problem? Please post your own answer if you did.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the situation is on Macs, but on Windows you get the windowClosing() callback from the close button; `Alt-F4`; and if you close the app via task manager. You don't get the callback if you use task manager to kill the process, but I wouldn't expect that anyway.

You have remembered to call `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);` on your JFrame instance, haven't you?

Answer (score 2):

there is one more method [windowClosed()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)
try overriding thing method. hope it will work for you.

Comment: +1 example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613577/java-how-do-i-prevent-windowclosing-from-actually-closing-the-window/7613768#7613768

Comment: looks like (for me) windowClosing gets called if they hit the X (and windowClosed doesn't), and windowClosed gets called if I programmatically call dispose. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to add some `KeyListeners` and a factory to detect the one you want for a particular operating system.

[Check Out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this osx library: 
[com.apple.eawt.ApplicationListener](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Reference/1.5.0/appledoc/api/com/apple/eawt/ApplicationListener.html)

```
handleQuit(ApplicationEvent event)
```

Will probably do the trick.

Information from the docs:

> Called when the application is sent the Quit event. This event is generated when the user selects Quit from the application menu, when the user types Command-Q, or when the user control clicks on your application icon in the Dock and chooses Quit. You can either accept or reject the request to quit.

Of course this solution will not work on Windows. As far as I know there is however no universal solution, so this is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As you said windowClosing is called when you click the (x) button. I am also on a mac and the way I get the CMD+Q to send a signal to the application is using [Runtime.addShutDownHook](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code to run when CMD+Q is pressed
    }
}
```