# Prevent parent window from closing while child window is opened/running

Tags: java, javafx

How to prevent parent window from closing while child window is opened/running. And if possible, parent window will not be disabled.

Answer (score 4):

The "normal" UI theme to do that is to make the child window *modal*. Meaning: the UI only allows to deal with the child window, and thus prevents any other clicks or actions that would affect the parent window.

But:

> And if possible, parent window will not be disabled.

If you really want that, then the child can't be modal. Then you have to do all these things manually. In other words: you have to implement WindowListeners, ActionListeners, ... on your parent window that intercept any attempts to close that window. And depending on "child window is up" prevent or allow that. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613577/java-how-do-i-prevent-windowclosing-from-actually-closing-the-window) for a first glance. But depending on what exactly your parent window is able to do, you are looking for a lot of other work, too!

And please note: as said, this means a lot of work **and** it is not what most people would expect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Will check it out.

Comment: @NewbieCoder You are very welcome ... and it case the answer is sufficient, feel free to accept. Otherwise let me know if you need more infos.

Comment: Note, in JavaFX, you only need `window.setOnCloseRequest(event -> { if (otherWindow.isShowing()) { event.consume(); } });` if you don't want use use a modal window.

Comment: @Slaw Maybe. Or there is a menu item to close the window, and another action here or there. Dont make promises that aren't easy to hold ...

Comment: Well, you could always fire a `WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST` from inside those menu items/other actions instead of calling `Window#hide()` ;) But I see your point.